# How to do a "even" extension of a plot in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, transpose

```
clc
clear all
z=[1 2 3 4 5];
d=[10 20 30 40 50];
plot(d,z)

z=[z fliplr(z)];
z(5)=[];
d=[d fliplr(d)];
d(5)=[];
figure(2)
plot(d,z)

z=[1 2 3 4 5];
z=[z 6 7 8 9];

figure(3)
plot(d,z)
```

I'm trying to "flip a graph on itself" or "fold it" , the first figure does this "/" the second one ALSO does "/" but it goes forward and then backwards, the third one does ">" and i need it to do "/\"or "^" whatever you think depicts it better, basically repeat the somewhat transpose of a graph, i need a mirror in front of it, something like doing even extensions in Fourier series i believe?
The problem is more complex than this, but this step is vital to keep doing it, please help me do so :/, i AM using Octave, but for something as basic as this MATLAB and Octave codes should be interchangeable.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even extension means f(-x) = f(x): same z-value when the argument d changes sign. The process you describe is not exactly that, since the reflected part is to be added at the end of original plot, to make /\ shape out of / shape.  This is how it can be done:

```
ze = [z z(end-1:-1:1)] 
de = [d 2*d(end)-d(end-1:-1:1)]
plot(de, ze)
```

The z-value are just reflected (repeated from end-1 to 1, in reverse order); the d-values are transformed by the map that sends x to 2*d(end) - x. This is a reflection that keeps d(end) fixed.

In your example,  ze is [1   2   3   4   5   4   3   2   1] and 
de is [10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90].

Comment: Thank you so very much! i was REALLY close to getting it with my last attempt but not quite, your input was the thing i needed, thanks a lot once again, i can't +1 because i don't seem to have the reputation :c

Comment: You can opt to accept the answer to let the community know that you no longer need help. Click on the checkmark icon at the top of the post, to the left below the up and down voting arrows.